# Validation Rule - either both entered or both blank

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I'm trying to validate to allow either `field1` and `field2` both be populated or both be blank.

I have tried this formula but does not seems to be working:

```
IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK(field1__c)),
    NOT(ISBLANK(field2__c)),
    NULL
)
```

Comment: Do you want to *allow* both blank/populated or block that behavior?

Comment: if the field1 has value then field2 should also have value or if field2 has value then field1 should have value, and lastly if the user has not entered any value in field1 or field2 then should not fire any validations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest implementation would be:

```
ISBLANK(Field1__c) != ISBLANK(Field2__c)
```

Next most accessible:

```
OR(
    AND(ISBLANK(Field1__c), NOT(ISBLANK(Field2__c))),
    AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Field1__c)), ISBLANK(Field2__c))
)
```

---

It doesn't make sense to return `NULL` in your validation formula, the result should always be `true` (error) or `false` (no error). If you want to use the approach you have above, your else condition should be `ISBLANK(Field2__c)`. To implement this strategy, however, you also need to apply the converse. The advantage of this approach is that you can add the error to each field.

Rule 1:

```
IF(
    ISBLANK(Field1__c),
    NOT(ISBLANK(Field2__c)),
    ISBLANK(Field2__c)
)
```

Rule 2:

```
IF(
    ISBLANK(Field2__c),
    NOT(ISBLANK(Field1__c)),
    ISBLANK(Field1__c)
)
```

Comment: did not work, i able to enter in feidl1 and save the record, yes my validation is active

Comment: Seems like `ISBLANK` does not really work like you'd expect. Try `ISNULL` instead. @Nick

Comment: `ISNULL(Field1__c) = ISNULL(Field2__c)` does not work

Comment: @Nick Sorry, should've been when they're *not* equal. Dumb mistake. I included the other two obvious approaches for completeness.

Comment: Hey Adrian: I forgot to mentioned that my page is a Visualforce page and I have `<apex:pageMessages />` but I still do not see any errors and I have entered some value in field1 and I left it as it is the field2 and hit save and it saved the record

Comment: Yeah, I just accidentally inverted the equality operator in my initial answer. The updated validations work for me and I ran through all four use cases (either one blank, both populated, both empty).

Comment: 1+ yep its work now `!=`

Answer (score 0):

OR(AND(ISNULL(Field1__c),ISNULL(Field2__c)),AND(NOT(ISNULL(Field1__c)),NOT(ISNULL(Field2__c))))

Hope this works.

Comment: did not work either